# Number of steps to reduce to zero

Tags: python

Hello I have this steps problem and I am trying to see where I can improve my code to get the number of steps it takes to reduce any integer down to zero. I'm sure you all know the process, but just for clarification...if the number is even, we divide by 2, adding a step, and if the number is odd we subtract, adding another step...Can someone let me know what im missing?

```
def steps_to_zero(int):
    step = 0
    while (abs(int) > 0):
        if int % 2 == 0:
            int / 2
        else:
            int - 1
        step += 1
    return step
```

Comment: Why had you tagged this with `[javascript]`

Comment: `int - 1` just computes that value. If you don't store the result somewhere, it is useless

Comment: It's better not to use `keyword` as `variable` names. I would suggest you to change `int` variable to some other name.

Comment: Don't use *int* as a variable name. *abs()* is irrelevant. Validate the input (think about what would happen if the parameter is -ve)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone! Didn't realize i had js tagged...first time posting on here and just finished learning js lol. Also Thank you for keyword information....in regards to abs(), part of the question said that the integer has to be a non-negative number so thats why i thought it would make sense

Comment: @jobaa1 Since you mentioned `abs`: Be aware that, just like `x/2`, doing `abs(int)` doesn't actually change the value of `int`! You'd have to do `int = abs(int)` for that to happen. In your original code, all `abs` does is make the while-loop keep going as long as `int != 0`, even if it is a negative integer. It should still work, however.

Comment: @stelioslogothetis in this case, as they ask for a non-negative number..would my method using abs be best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a line such as `x / 2`, Python will calculate the result of that division. However, you aren't saving the *result* of the division anywhere!

You need to do the same thing you're doing with `step += 1`, which is equivalent to `step = step + 1`:

```
def steps_to_zero(int):
    step = 0
    while (abs(int) > 0):
        if int % 2 == 0:
            int /= 2 # Same as int = int / 2
        else:
            int -= 1 # Same as int = int - 1
        step += 1 # Same as step = step + 1
    return step
```

If you don't do this, the variable `int` never changes values. It keeps the value it had at the start. And as a result, the while-loop keeps running forever, since `abs(int) > 0` stays the case forever.

Another note, [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is a built-in type and has special meaning. It is heavily recommended to not use it, or any other such type, as names for your variables. Consider writing `integer` instead:

```
def steps_to_zero(integer):
    step = 0
    while (abs(integer) > 0):
        if integer % 2 == 0:
            integer /= 2 # Same as integer = integer / 2
        else:
            integer -= 1 # Same as integer = integer - 1
        step += 1 # Same as step = step + 1
    return step
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not updating your counter `int`. You need to store it back to itself, or you'll be looping forever.

```
def steps_to_zero(int):
    step = 0
    while (abs(int) > 0):
        if int % 2 == 0:
            int = int / 2
        else:
            int = int - 1
        step += 1
    return step
```

Should solve it.